# calculating the difference between two dates in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, diff

I have a table  called transactions . I want to be able to measure days between the cmnt_cre_dates.

The table looks like this

```
pt_id   name              trans_cmnt    pt_loc  last_bl_date cmnt_cre_date
94578   RAMIREZ , JOHN    Trans 130     S       1/8/2015     1/8/2015
94578   RAMIREZ , JOHN    Trans 146     S       1/8/2015     1/9/2015
94578   RAMIREZ , JOHN    Trans 380     S       1/8/2015     1/13/2015
94578   RAMIREZ , JOHN    Trans 344     S       1/8/2015     1/15/2015
54678   KIFLE ,LOLA       Trans 146     S       1/16/2015    1/16/2015
54678   KIFLE ,LOLA       Trans 230     S       1/16/2015    1/16/2015
12547   WEISS ,Jenny      Trans 230     S       1/26/2015    1/26/2015
12711   FARRELL ,DIVINA   Trans 230     S       1/14/2015    1/14/2015
12711   JOHNS ,NATIVIDAD  Trans 230     S       1/23/2015    1/13/2015
12711   JOHNS ,NATIVIDAD  Trans 230     S       1/23/2015    1/23/2015
```

I would like the table to look like this:

```
pt_id   name             trans_cmnt pt_loc last_bl_date cmnt_cre_date   diff_days
94578   RAMIREZ , JOHN   Trans 130  S      1/8/2015     1/8/2015         0
94578   RAMIREZ , JOHN   Trans 146  S      1/8/2015     1/9/2015         1
94578   RAMIREZ , JOHN   Trans 380  S      1/8/2015     1/13/2015        4
94578   RAMIREZ , JOHN   Trans 344  S      1/8/2015     1/15/2015        2
54678   KIFLE ,LOLA      Trans 146  S      1/16/2015    1/16/2015        0
54678   KIFLE ,LOLA      Trans 230  S      1/16/2015    1/16/2015        0
12547   WEISS ,Jenny     Trans 230  S      1/26/2015    1/26/2015        0
12711   FARRELL ,DIVINA  Trans 230  S      1/14/2015    1/14/2015        0
12711   JOHNS ,NATIVIDAD Trans 230  S      1/23/2015    1/13/2015        0
12711   JOHNS ,NATIVIDAD Trans 230  S      1/23/2015    1/23/2015       10
```

How do I do this in sql?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly...

```
update your_table current set diff_days = 
 cmnt_cre_date - (select max(cmnt_cre_date) from your_table 
                  where cmnt_cre_date < current.cmnt_cre_date
                  and name = current.name) ;

update your_table set diff_days = 0 where diff_days is null;
```

The above is in postgres, since you didn't specify which database you are using.

Comment: I am not familiar with postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can work along

```
SELECT
  T.pt_id
  , T.name
  , T.trans_cmnt
  , T.pt_loc
  , T.last_bl_date
  , T.cmnt_cre_date
  , ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,
                    (SELECT MAX(cmnt_cre_date)
                     FROM Transactions
                     WHERE name = T.name AND cmnt_cre_date < T.cmnt_cre_date),
                    cmnt_cre_date),
           0) diff_days
FROM Transactions T
;
```

Please remember: You can't rely on the records to be returned in some specific order, if you don't provide an `ORDER BY` clause.

Please comment if and as adjustment / further detail is required.